# Install specific version of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I have trouble installing a specific version of Visual Studio 2017.
Microsoft released the new Update 3 (Version 15.3.1) and they only provide an online installer. This one installs the most recent version, which always includes the update 3.
[image]

The problem is that I need to install VS 2017 Update 2, but I found no way of doing that. I already had a look in creating an offline installation, but there is no argument for setting a specific version.

Do you know of any way to install VS 2017 with an older version then update 3?

Comment: Can you tell us *why* you want to go back to an older version of Visual Studio 2017? I'm pretty sure Microsoft would be interested in knowing about compatibility issues that 15.3 or 15.3.1 introduced.

Comment: In any case, I think you need to contact Microsoft about this. If you have a offline installation from 15.2 lying around you can always pull the plug on your network and install that but I think the installer will automatically pull the latest bits if you allow it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I can't speak for the OP, but I arrived at this question because Intel's Fortran Compiler 2017u4 doesn't support VS2017u3.  However, it *does* work with VS2017u2 and earlier.  I need a way to explicitly install VS2017u2 so I can continue to work.  Without a way to select a specific version, I'm stuck waiting for Intel to release yet another update, or relegated to installing VS2015 instead.

Comment: @Someone because 15.3, 15.4 are totaly broken versions for us until 15.5 release(hope)

Comment: Too late now, but: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017  Unfortunately I can't find similar documentation or downloads for VS 2019 or I would update the question and write an answer