# Install older version of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How do I install an older version of Visual Studio 2017?

I'm on 15.3.2, due to a bug I want to downgrade to 15.2.

Comment: I am at a loss. I've even tried running the 15.2 chocolatey install: https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2017enterprise Somehow the installed version is still 15.3.2!

Comment: Duplicate of [Install specific version of Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818632/install-specific-version-of-visual-studio-2017).

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft released an installer for build 15.2.6 in late September 2017:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

I was able to install Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2.6 which is not the most recent (15.3+). The page includes links for Community, Professional and Enterprise. Here's the bootstrapper link for Visual Studio Professional:
https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/3f9b192f9/vs_Professional.exe